# Trying to convert struct with hashmap member

Tags: rust

Consider a struct:

```rust
struct RawData{
  pub a: HashMap<String, String>,
  pub b: HashMap<String, String>,
}
```

which should be converted in a struct with more concrete members:

```rust
struct EncodedData{
  pub a: HashMap<String, MyStruct>,
  pub b: HashMap<String, MyStruct>,
}
```

and there is a function which tries to parse `String` into `MyStruct` returning `Result<MyStruct, String>`

Now I am not happy with the working solution I found and think there must be a better solution:

```rust
fn convert(raw_data: RawData) -> Result<EncodedData, String> {
    let a: Result<HashMap<String, MyStruct>, String> = raw_data
        .a
        .iter()
        .map(|(k, v)| {
            let v = parse(v.clone())?;
            Ok((k.clone(), v))
        })
        .collect();
    let a = a?;
    let b: Result<HashMap<String, MyStruct>, String> = raw_data
        .b
        .iter()
        .map(|(k, v)| {
            let v = parse(v.clone())?;
            Ok((k.clone(), v))
        })
        .collect();
    let b = b?;
    Ok(EncodedData { a, b })
}
```

Here is a complete working example:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[macro_use]
extern crate maplit;

struct MyStruct {
    code: String,
}

struct RawData {
    pub a: HashMap<String, String>,
    pub b: HashMap<String, String>,
}

struct EncodedData {
    pub a: HashMap<String, MyStruct>,
    pub b: HashMap<String, MyStruct>,
}

fn parse(code: String) -> Result<MyStruct, String> {
    Ok(MyStruct { code })
}

fn convert(raw_data: RawData) -> Result<EncodedData, String> {
    let a: Result<HashMap<String, MyStruct>, String> = raw_data
        .a
        .iter()
        .map(|(k, v)| {
            let v = parse(v.clone())?;
            Ok((k.clone(), v))
        })
        .collect();
    let a = a?;
    let b: Result<HashMap<String, MyStruct>, String> = raw_data
        .b
        .iter()
        .map(|(k, v)| {
            let v = parse(v.clone())?;
            Ok((k.clone(), v))
        })
        .collect();
    let b = b?;
    Ok(EncodedData { a, b })
}

fn main() {
    let raw = RawData {
        a: hashmap! {"a".to_string() => "b".to_string()},
        b: hashmap! {"c".to_string() => "d".to_string()},
    };

    let _ = convert(raw);
}
```

with additional dependency:
`maplit = "^1.0.1"`

Here I don't like:
1. the need of clone, because `into_iter()` is not allowed.
1. the second `let a = a?;` because otherwise the compiler could not infer the type.

Cargo clippy seems to be happy with that code. Are you?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. the need of clone, because into_iter() is not allowed

Well, into_iter() is allowed, and you can just use that and then you don't need clone.

> 1. the second let a = a?; because otherwise the compiler could not infer the type.

Yeah, Rust doesn't handle inferring the error type when using ? very nicely.

The best strategy I've found so far is to move these things into reusable generic functions. For example:

```
fn map_hash_values<K: std::cmp::Eq + std::hash::Hash, V1, V2, E>(
    data: HashMap<K, V1>,
    f: impl Fn(V1) -> Result<V2, E>,
) -> Result<HashMap<K, V2>, E> {
    data.into_iter().map(|(k, v)| Ok((k, f(v)?))).collect()
}

fn convert(raw_data: RawData) -> Result<EncodedData, String> {
    Ok(EncodedData {
        a: map_hash_values(raw_data.a, parse)?,
        b: map_hash_values(raw_data.b, parse)?,
    })
}
```